# TcpConnection capable of handling concurrent requests. Client-Server

Tags: c#, concurrency, tcp, client-server

I'm trying to build a simple Client-Server Application with the following codes:

```
//SERVER
IPAddress ipAd = IPAddress.Parse("192.163.10.101");
TcpListener myList = new TcpListener(ipAd, 8001);
myList.Start();

Console.WriteLine("The server is running at port 8001...");
Console.WriteLine("The local End point is  :" + myList.LocalEndpoint);
Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a connection.....");

Socket s = myList.AcceptSocket();
Console.WriteLine("Connection accepted from " + s.RemoteEndPoint);

//CLIENT
TcpClient tcpclnt = new TcpClient();
Console.WriteLine("Connecting.....");
tcpclnt.Connect("192.163.10.101",8001); 
Console.WriteLine("Connected");
```

this actually does what I need wherein the client can connect to the server. However, when I try to run multiple instances of the client to connect with the server, the server only accepts the first client to connect. Meaning there's like a one-to-one connection wherein only one client can connect with the client. However, what I need is to give the server the ability to accept connections from more than one client.

If anyone can point me a possible solution to this, I'll really be appreciative! Thanks!

Comment: If the first client disconnects, can you connect a second client?

Comment: yes I can. what I wanna achieve is to make the server accept multiple connected clients. :) thanks for the response!

Answer (score 1):

You need to call AcceptSocket again to accept another socket.
A typical design would be to have to call BeginAcceptSocket and in the callback call EndAcceptSocket, dispatch the client processing to its own thread (or a worker thread using async methods) and then call BeginAcceptSocket again.

This fragment is untested but should be more or less right/ get you thinking in the right direction.

```
class Server
{
    public Server()
    {
        TcpListener listener = null;

        // init the listener

        listener.BeginAcceptSocket((ar) => AcceptLoop(ar, listener),null);
    }

    public void HandleClientSocketRead(IAsyncResult ar, byte[] recvBuffer, Socket clientSocket)
    {
        int recvd = clientSocket.EndReceive(ar);
        //do something with the data
        clientSocket.BeginReceive(recvBuffer, 0, 1024, SocketFlags.None, (ar2) => HandleClientSocketRead(ar2, recvBuffer, clientSocket), null);
    }

    public void AcceptLoop(IAsyncResult ar, TcpListener listener)
    {
        Socket clientSocket = listener.EndAcceptSocket(ar); // note that this can throw
        byte[] recvBuffer = new byte[1024];

        clientSocket.BeginReceive(recvBuffer, 0, 1024, SocketFlags.None, (ar2) => HandleClientSocketRead(ar2, recvBuffer, clientSocket), null);

        listener.BeginAcceptSocket((ar) => AcceptLoop(ar, listener), null);
    }
}
```

Comment: if I use this code as my server, do I have to change parts of my client? i'm sorry but i think i'm confused. thanks for the help! :)

Comment: no.  It is perfectly acceptable to do async operations on the server and synchronous operations on the client.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to write a server, a good design is to have a [server].exe and a [client].exe. The [server].exe, will of course accept and process all incoming connections, maintain the client sockets, and perform whatever actions you need. Below is a **very** basic example on writing a server to accept multiple client sockets, and store them in a List object. This, however, is not multithreaded so the code, does block.

**[server].exe**

```
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <copyright file="Program.cs" company="DCOM Productions">
//     Copyright (c) DCOM Productions.  All rights reserved.
// </copyright>
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace MultiSocketServerExample {
    using System;
    using System.Net.Sockets;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    class Program {

        static List<Socket> m_ConnectedClients = new List<Socket>();

        static void Main(string[] args) {
            Socket host = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            host.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 9999));
            host.Listen(1);

            while (true) {
                m_ConnectedClients.Add(host.Accept());
                Console.WriteLine("A client connected.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then to work with your clients: (Again, **very** basic example)

```
m_ConnectedClients[0].Send(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("hello!");
```

Network programming with the Socket class is a lot easier in my opinion then using TcpListener and TcpClient. The reason I say this is that it is already a really good and easy to use implementation, and by using TcpListener and TcpClient where they create further abstraction, lessenes your ability to understand what is going on (in my opinion).

Comment: if i'm going to use this type of code for my server then I probably should place my code inside the while loop too right? i mean cos I have to accept some inputs from the user and process it with the server.

Comment: Think about what your application needs to do. You need a client that connects to a server, can accept multiple commands (ongoing), and send to and be processed by the server. In that order. 1) Write code to connect 2) Accept input 3) Send to server 4) wait for response (that is the order for the client side), so correct, you need a loop to accept the input. Immediately after input prepare, send, and wait for a response, then loop and start over